# How to import "HttpClient" to Eclipse?

Tags: java

How do I import "HttpClient" in Eclipse? I downloaded HttpClient from http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi just now. I added it to my Eclipse new java project and want to run a example copy from website.

This example uses `import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;` But, what pity is, it shows that Eclipse can't resolve this.

Now, I want to know the right way to import new released HttpClient to my project.
Is it necessary to add some jar to classpath? What is it?

This is the whole example I run. I guess new released "HTTPClient" changed its import jar, is it true?

```
package http.demo; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*; 
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;

public class SimpleHttpClient { 
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      client.getHostConfiguration().setHost( "www.imobile.com.cn" , 80, "http" );
      method = getPostMethod();    
      client.executeMethod(method);  
      System.out.println(method.getStatusLine());   
      Stringresponse=newString(method.getResponseBodyAsString().getBytes("8859_1"));

      System.out.println(response);
      method.releaseConnection();
   }


   private static HttpMethod getGetMethod(){
      return new GetMethod("/simcard.php?simcard=1330227");
   }

    private static HttpMethod getPostMethod(){
      PostMethod post = new PostMethod( "/simcard.php" );
      NameValuePair simcard = new NameValuePair( "simcard" , "1330227" );
      post.setRequestBody( new NameValuePair[] { simcard});
      return post; 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You drag the jar file to your project so you can see it inside Eclipse.

To give it special meaning to Eclipse, right click on the jar file inside Eclipse and select Build Path ->  Add to Build Path.

Now your imports should resolve properly.

Comment: weather it need add classpath or not? i find it in IBM website.it is says i need viste http://jakarta.apache.org/site/downloads/downloads_commons-logging.cgi and downloading "common logging"，and then add commons-logging.jar to CLASSPATH .But ,this link is not avaliable.what should i do?

Comment: Sounds like the article is a little old.  Log4j is these days found at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html

Comment: yeap.the article is post in 2005.i cant find new realeased article about how to import this.Now.Can u give me a whole process about import "httpclient" to my Eclipse? what shoud u i download and weather should i add commons-logging.jar to classpath with latest “httpClient” version?thx~

Comment: @alex, I think you should pick an easier project before embarking on this one.  Do you have a more experienced person around you to help you?

Comment: I followed the instructions in http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html : "The first thing you need to do is get a copy of HttpClient and its dependencies. This tutorial was written for HttpClient 3.0. You will also need JDK 1.3 or above.
Once you've downloaded HttpClient and dependencies you will need to put them on your classpath. There is also an optional dependency on JSSE which is required for HTTPS connections; this is not required for this tutorial." Still doesn't work for me... it does not want to resolve the import.

Comment: Seems that "org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore_4.1.3.jar" must be included in the classpath too. Can be downloaded at http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi

Answer (score 14):

It works, it Solved:

1. first download file JAR from web apache https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi.
2. extract file zip
3. open your eclipse project
4. Do right click libs on the Package Explorer and choose Build Path -> Configure Build Path
5. Choose Java Build Path on the left side box
6. Click tab Libraries.
7. Add External JAR, choose your extracted file on point (2)
8. You may choose all file JAR on extracted file, it depends on your imported at your project.

Comment: @SteveStaple you need to open the links in the section KEYS - Binary. When you download the zip, inside there are the jars (in lib).

Comment: Which should I use?

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to:
   https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi
2. download the *****.tar.gz file
3. extract it
4. go inside the lib folder, there you'll find all the JARs
5. open Eclipse, right click on your project -> Properties -> Java Build Path ->
   Libraries tab -> Add External JARs - > choose all the JARs in lib (step 4)
6. to test I recommend you try to run some code that uses this library like:
   http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/
7. you'll probably see a red underline, hover it and choose Import.....

good luck