# import org.apache error, (http client)

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, httpclient

This question is almost 100% alike with mine.

[How to import "HttpClient" to Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290419/how-to-import-httpclient-to-eclipse)

I am just wondering what .jar file they are talking about in the response. When I download the example code I see .jar files in the lib folder. I right click on my project and go to properties----> add external jars and add them to my project but this does not work. Can someone please help?

Thanks

Edit: I downloaded the Binary file from http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi and used the jar files there

Also I downloaded http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/logging/log4j/1.2.16/apache-log4j-1.2.16.zip and added the jar here to my project, as discussed in the comments of the other question

Comment: Is this HttpClient 3 or HttpClient 4?

Comment: I dont quite know the difference, how do I tell

Comment: Do you still have this problem?