# How to install org.apache.commons.httpclient in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I need to install this library: org.apache.commons.httpclient.
I`we tried unsing Help -> Install new software but I can`t find it there

Please help me I` would need to use in my program these:

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.MultipartPostMethod;
```

Comment: I think your question is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290419/how-to-import-httpclient-to-eclipse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to install it. Search for the jar containing it and then in eclipse right click on your project -> build path. In the new window, go to libraries, add a new user library and in that new one, add your jars.

Answer (score 3):

Download **"commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar"** adn save to your local hard disk. 
Go to you **project, right click/properties/java build path/library/Add External library**.
Provide the path to the jar saved on your hard disk and press ok. You can use the classes(HttpClient,MultipartPostMethod) available in the jar.

Thank you