# Error in importing "java.io" package

Tags: android

If the problem is that I have no package embedded in my SDK. Then please tell me how to add packages in eclipse.

> Below is my code

```
package coin.asiannews;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

import coin.asiannews.utils.ShakeDetector;
import coin.asiannews.utils.ShakeDetector.OnShakeListener;

/** Extend from this Activity to display the navigation drawer on the left side
 * 
 * @author Pixelart Web and App Development
 */
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    View devi;
    ListView mDrawerList;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    protected FrameLayout contentLayout;
    int id = 0;
    ArrayList<String> idList;
    AlertDialog ad;
    boolean isTablet = false;

    /** Set The ContentView and the position in the menu list
     * 
     * @param layoutResID
     * @param position
     */
    public void setContentView(final int layoutResID, int id) {
        this.id = id;
        devi = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base, null);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) devi.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mDrawerLayout= (DrawerLayout) devi.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        contentLayout= (FrameLayout) devi.findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, contentLayout, true);
        super.setContentView(devi);

        // Set this to true to display an icon or logo
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        // Set this to false to hide text title
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        if(((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)contentLayout.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin == 240) {
            isTablet = true;
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }else {
            isTablet = false;
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        if(isTablet) {
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
            mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

        }else if(!isTablet) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,
                    R.string.drawer_close) {

                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            };

            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        }

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        String[] menu = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_drawer_menu, menu));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(id, true);

        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(BaseActivity.this);
        if(pref.getBoolean("isDeviceShake", true) == true){
            ShakeDetector.create(this, new OnShakeListener() {
                public void OnShake() {
                        randomPost();
                }
             });
        }

    }

    public void setItemChecked() {
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(id, true);  
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        ShakeDetector.start();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(id, true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
         super.onStop();
         ShakeDetector.stop();
     }

    @Override
     protected void onDestroy() {
         super.onDestroy();
         ShakeDetector.destroy();
     }

    public void displayDrawerToggle(boolean ddt) {
        if(ddt) {
            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        }else if(!ddt) {
            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(!isTablet) {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if(!isTablet) {
            mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (!isTablet && mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
           return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }   

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {

            case 0:
                Intent latest = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, LatestPosts.class);
                startActivity(latest);
                if(!isTablet) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent categories = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, CategoriesIndex.class);
                startActivity(categories);
                if(!isTablet) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent page = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, PageActivity.class);
                startActivity(page);
                if(!isTablet) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                Intent bookmarks = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, BookmarkPosts.class);
                startActivity(bookmarks);
                if(!isTablet) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                Intent settings = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(settings);
                if(!isTablet) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
                break;
            }
        } };      


    /**
     * RANDOM POST FUNCTIONS
     */
    private void randomPost() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_shake, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setView(dialoglayout);
        ad = builder.create();
        ad.show();

        String param = "/get_posts/?include=id&count=999999";
        String api = getString(R.string.api);
        String url = getString(R.string.blogurl);

        url = url+api+param;
        new GetIdsTask().execute(url);
    }

    private class GetIdsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if (null != idList) {
                Random r = new Random();
                int index = r.nextInt(idList.size());
                String pId = idList.get(index);
                fetchPost(pId);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url = params[0];
            JSONObject json = getJSONFromUrl(url);

            try {

                if (json.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
                    JSONArray posts = json.getJSONArray("posts");

                    idList = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject post = (JSONObject) posts.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = post.getString("id");

                        idList.add(id);
                    }
                }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        JSONObject jObj = null;
        String json = null;

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {}

        return jObj;
    }

    private void fetchPost(String id) {
        String url = getString(R.string.blogurl);
        String api = getString(R.string.api);
        String include = getString(R.string.include);
        String param = "/get_post/?id="+id+"&include="+include;

        url = url+api+param;
        new GetPostTask().execute(url);
    }

    private class GetPostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

        String[] postData;

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {         
            Intent intent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, PostDetails.class);
            intent.putExtra("post_url", postData[0]);
            intent.putExtra("post_title", postData[1]);
            intent.putExtra("post_id", postData[2]);
            intent.putExtra("post_com_status", postData[3]);
            intent.putExtra("post_author", postData[4]);
            startActivity(intent);

            ad.cancel();    
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url = params[0];
            JSONObject json = getJSONFromUrl(url);

            try {

                if (json.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("ok")) {
                    JSONObject post = json.getJSONObject("post");
                        String id = post.getString("id");
                        String title = post.getString("title");
                        String uri = post.getString("url");
                        String com_status = post.getString("comment_status");

                        JSONObject aut = post.getJSONObject("author");
                        String author = aut.getString("name");

                      String[]  postData = { uri, title, id, com_status, author, };
                      this.postData = postData;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }   
}
```

I am getting this error while importing **IO** package, not able to find reson for this problem. Any help will be of great value.

--Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your Eclipse preferences:

**Java -> Installed JREs.** The one that you're using should be marked and it should be a JDK not just a JRE.

Also check your project's build path:

> Right click on the project -> Properties -> Java Build Path Check in
> the "libraries" folder whether the JRE System Library is present and
> if not add it using "Add library"->"JRE System Library" and then
> select the correct one (from an installed JDK).

Comment: Thankew.. but what for org?

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting you (org)

Comment: Sir, its  import org.apache.http.httpEntity? I have a problem in this also.

Comment: have you added related jar to use this library?

Comment: No, i have not added related jar in my project.

Comment: Will you please give me the link to the jar of this file.. And  i have problem in all import statements.

Comment: kindly follow this steps mentioned in this link, http://stackoverflow.com/a/32601515/5722385

Comment: here you can find the jar,  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadapachehttpcomponentshttpcorejar.htm

Comment: I have issue for import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24998802/5722385, refer this, I would suggest start using Android Studio friend!

Comment: I can't get it. please explain

Comment: See you are getting all this errors as the Classes you are trying to access is not available with your project, so to resolve HttpEntity, you have added one external Jar, simillarly ActionBarDrawerToggle is not, but this is part of android SDK so you need to either update SDK or add jar as show in the answer on the link I suggested (answer by Elenasys). And to avoid all this complication you can use Android studio, its very easy to use and no need to add jar.