# HTTPClient GetMethod()

Tags: java, httpclient

I am new to using Apache HTTPClient and had a quick question about what a certain line of code means. I was going through SO and found this sample code and was reading the documentation in order to learn how to implement in my own project. The code below is from [How to import "HttpClient" to Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290419/how-to-import-httpclient-to-eclipse)

```
package http.demo; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*; 
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;

public class SimpleHttpClient { 
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      client.getHostConfiguration().setHost( "www.imobile.com.cn" , 80, "http" );
      method = getPostMethod();    
      client.executeMethod(method);  
      System.out.println(method.getStatusLine());   
      Stringresponse=newString(method.getResponseBodyAsString().getBytes("8859_1"));

      System.out.println(response);
      method.releaseConnection();
   }


   private static HttpMethod getGetMethod(){
      return new GetMethod("/simcard.php?simcard=1330227");
   }

    private static HttpMethod getPostMethod(){
      PostMethod post = new PostMethod( "/simcard.php" );
      NameValuePair simcard = new NameValuePair( "simcard" , "1330227" );
      post.setRequestBody( new NameValuePair[] { simcard});
      return post; 
   } 
}
```

Can some explain in laymen's terms what the simcard lines are referring to exactly and how they relate to the getGetMethod and getPostMethod (these are the last two blocks of code).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines instantiate a HttpClient with base URL of the server

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.getHostConfiguration().setHost( "www.imobile.com.cn" , 80, "http" );
```

and then following is accessing a particular resource from that HTTP server.

```
method = getPostMethod();    
client.executeMethod(method);
```

Following line is actually creating GetMethod object with `sub url`

```
new GetMethod("/simcard.php?simcard=1330227");
```

so seeing is completely is like making get request to -

```
www.imobile.com.cn/simcard.php?simcard=1330227
```

Comment: OK - so I am (or the program user is) the client and the iomobile site is the server? What exactly is the person trying to accomplish with this code? Are they just setting up a connection for requests? Why wouldn't the first part with the iomobile url be the server?

Comment: Also when I actually visit the site: http://www.imobile.com.cn/simcard it produces an error

Comment: Awesome thanks so much. Is there any particular reason why the site is producing an error when you type the url into your browser?

Comment: That might be the issue with the API itself, however this is how HttpClient and GET, POST work in general :)

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with HttpCleint, By api i was referring to http://www.imobile.com.cn/simcard api

Comment: That makes sense. Apache would follow best practices and is open source so  any possible issues would almost certainly lie with the imobile site