# How can I make an http post request using java on android

Tags: java, android, http, post, request

How can I hit an api post end point using java and pass a body as a json data ?

I found this code on the android docs but I don't know how to pass the request body

```
 URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
 HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 try {
   urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
   urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
   OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
   writeStream(out);

   InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
   readStream(in);
} finally {
   urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: If you can add dependency to  your project i recommend you to take look around http client like okHttp client

Comment: With this code, you pass the request body by writing it to `out`. Just make sure everything is written before you get the input stream.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**I am kotlin Guy but this is how I have done post request in java**

```
new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream requestWriter = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        requestWriter.writeBytes(JsonBodyObject.toString());
        requestWriter.close();
        BufferedReader responseReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String responseData = responseReader.readLine();
        activity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseData);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        });
        responseReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use http client and it goes really well, (unless you send a delete call with body).

Here you have all the info you need to import it and get it done.

[How to import "HttpClient" to Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290419/how-to-import-httpclient-to-eclipse)

With this you can get your call running if you have problems building the thing with httpClient, send your code in this question and i will try to help.